# Calculadora basica en c# y un label

Tags: c#

Veran, como dice el titulo estoy haciendo una calculadora. Mi inquietud es la de como mandar un label los valores que se estan sumando en una suma de varios numeros, ejemplo: 4+5+10+8+7 y asi, que me vaya acumulando los valores que vaya metiendo en el label

Answer (score 1):

Podrias hacer una funcion que reciba el Parametro o texto que le envies ejemplo

```
public void textAdd(string texto)
{
   milabel.text =  milabel.text + " " +  texto;
}
```

y la utilizas de la siguiente manera:

```
textAdd("5");
```

Donde el 5 es la letra que agregara, si tu lbel no tiene nada solo veras el 5